# Linkedlist and segmentaion fault

Tags: c

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct prefix {
   unsigned int IP ;
   unsigned char len ;
  struct prefix *next ;
 };
typedef struct prefix Prefix ;
int cal(int d){
   int i , sum ;
   sum = 2 ;
   for( i = 0 ; i < d-1 ; i++)
     sum = sum * 2 ;
      return sum+1 ; }


Prefix *insert_a_node(Prefix *head,Prefix *node ){
    Prefix *cur ;
      cur = head ;
    if(head == NULL)
        return node ;
    if( node == NULL )
       return head ;
    if( node->IP < head->IP)
      { node->next = head ;
          return node ;  }
    while( cur->next != NULL && cur->next->IP <= node->IP)
        cur = cur->next ;
       node->next = cur->next ;
       cur->next = node ;
      return head ;
                       }

void insert_prefix(Prefix *group_head,Prefix *node){
  int i = 0;
  Prefix *t;

  if(node == NULL) return;
  if(group_head->next == NULL)
        {
         group_head->next=node;

         return ;
        }
  if(node->IP <= group_head->next->IP)
        {
        node->next = group_head->next ;
        group_head->next=node;

        return ;
        }
  t = group_head->next ;
 if(t->next==NULL)
   {  t->next=node;

      return;}
  while(t->next!=NULL && t->next->IP < node->IP)
        t=t->next;
 if(t->next==NULL)
     { t->next=node;

       return;}
   else{
    node->next=t->next;
    t->next=node;

    return;}
}
Prefix *build_list_no_order(Prefix *head,Prefix *node){

     if (head == NULL)
         return node ;
     if (node == NULL)
        return head ;
   Prefix *cur ;
     cur = head ;
   while ( cur->next != NULL)
    cur = cur->next ;
    cur->next = node ;
  return head ;

 }

Prefix *build_routing_table(){
    int a[5],i ;
   int ip = 0 ;
  Prefix *head ;
      head =  NULL ;
 FILE *ofp ;
 ofp = fopen("routing_table","r") ;
 while( fscanf(ofp,"%d.%d.%d.%d/%d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4]) != EOF){
       Prefix *node = (Prefix*)malloc(sizeof(Prefix)) ;
   for ( i =0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
   {  ip = ip + a[i] ;
    if ( i != 3 )
      ip = ip<<8 ;  }
        node->IP = ip ;
        ip = 0 ;
        node->len=a[4];
      head = build_list_no_order(head,node);  }
 fclose(ofp);
    return head ;

    }

void segment(int d,Prefix *rout ,Prefix group[],int each_seg_num[]){
   int index=0,i;
 if(rout->len < d)
      index = cal(d)-1;
 else{
   for(i=31 ; i>31-d ; i--){
    if( ( rout->IP & 1<<i ) && ( i!=32-d))
        {index++;
        index=index<<1;}
    if( (rout->IP & 1<<i) && i==32-d)
        index++;
    if( !(rout->IP & 1<<i) && i!=32-d)
        index=index<<1;
                           }
      }
   each_seg_num[index]++;
   insert_prefix(&group[index],rout);
    return ;
   }
int main ( int argc , char *argv[]){
  Prefix *routing_head;
  Prefix *trace_head;
  Prefix *node;
  int d = 5 , i ; //need use argc finally
  int group_num;
  group_num = cal(d);
  Prefix group[group_num] ;
  int each_seg_num[group_num];
 for( i = 0 ; i < group_num ; i++)
  each_seg_num[i] = 0;
  routing_head = build_routing_table();
 int count = 1200 ;
 while(routing_head != NULL &&count>=0){
   node = routing_head ;
   routing_head = routing_head->next ;
   node->next = NULL ;
   segment(d,node,group,each_seg_num);
    count--;
     }
 for( i = 0 ; i < group_num ; i++)
   printf("%d\n",each_seg_num[i]);

     return 0 ;
}
```

Let me explain what i was doing now.

First,i read 80000 data from routing_table ( each data have similar
format like  2.10.120.20/8 ,and i store it in  Prefix's IP(unsigned int  ) you can call it IP/prefix length).
Then, I want segment these data into different group (each group is
one linked list) the number is decided by int d, assume d=2, so 
I have 2^2+1 group. Due to each data's first "d" bit, we can determine which
group should data go.
Example : IP(in binary):01000011......   it should get into group[1]
          IP  : 1000001.....     should get into group[2]
   and if prefix len < d   such as  IP: 1********(* means dont care bit) it should get into special group , group[4].
Third , each linkedlist should in order ( small to big)

Problem : I think i have already finish almost code, but when i execute my program
it have segmentation fault. But most surprise me is that when I use int count to
restrict how many data pass into segment(), the program can work !!
The code can work less than pass about 1000 data. I want to know how
to solve my problem, thank you for reading my question.

.....Last, my English maybe is not good enough to explain the question perfectly.....please forgive me ^^

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you take time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (as stackoverflow.com is not a free debugging service).

Comment: If the StackOverflow engine tells you "enter code here" and "link to ideone must be accompanied by code", then please heed those hints.

Comment: thank yours notification , i will keep them in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash occurs when in `insert_prefix`, where you insert a node into a group list while keeping the list sorted.

First, you have a conceptual error when defining the groups. There are `group_num` groups and each group is a linked list, so you need an array of pointers to prefix nodes instead of an array of nodes:

```
Prefix *group[group_num];
```

You should also initialise each pointer to `NULL`. And you must adjust the `group` argument to the `segment` and `insert_prefix`functions.

In your implementation of the unordered linked list, you return the new head node. Here, you must also find a means to update the head if necessary. In C, I find it useful to pass a pointer to the head node pointer.

You can use this pointer to a node pointer to iterate through the list: When you call the function, that pointer is the address of the head node. After that, it is the address of the previous node's `next` pointer.

With this technique, your function becomes:

```
void insert_prefix(Prefix **head, Prefix *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    while (*head && (*head)->IP < node->IP) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }

    node->next = *head;
    *head = node;
}
```

See how this iteration method takes care of all special cases. There's no need to distinguish between an empty and a full list.

The other changes to your program you should make are to change the `group` argument here:

```
void segment(int d, Prefix * rout, Prefix *group[], int each_seg_num[])
{
    ....
}
```

and to change the definition and initialisation in `main`:

```
group_num = cal(d);
Prefix *group[group_num];
int each_seg_num[group_num];

for (i = 0; i < group_num; i++) {
    group[i] = NULL;
    each_seg_num[i] = 0;
}
```

You should probably also introduce code to destroy your lists at the end of the program.

Comment: Your code in insert_prefix is absolutely new idea for me about linkedlist, thank you very much .But i still have 2 question about your answer.First, the code in your insert_prefix :head = &(*head)->next;  i think (*head)->next is the address owned by *next in Prefix , why did you add '&' ? Second, you said my code crashed in insert_prefix because  I insert a node into a group list while keeping the list sorted. I cant understand why they do at the same time . Thank for your reading

Comment: I didn't say the crash was "because" you inserted the node in orer, just that it happened there. I just put your code in a debugger, created some example data and found where the crash ocured. Once I saw the real problem (namely that the head pointers weren't pointers), I didn't try to find out what exactly happend. I think the pointer-to-node-pointer technique is worth knowing, so I just rewrite `insert_index` from scratch instead of trying to adapt your function.

Comment: The unary `&` operator takes the address of a variable and so creates a pointer to it. In this approach, the address is that of the pointer that points to the current node, which is `&head` at the beginning and `&prev->next` when you traverse the list. You can access and update these pointers via ´*head`. Because both cases are represented by just ´*head`, you don't need to distiguish these cases.